# Object Model Properties Not Assigned After Submitting The Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have view with UserSample model with two properties (Username, Password), All I want to achieve is to take these values from the textboxes and to store them into the object model and then in the Action method to take this object and manipulate it.

But here in this code the object properties in the action method Index are always null after submitting the form with filled text box fields.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(UserSample user) //this is the object which properties I want to be asigned.
        {
            if (user != null)
            {

            }

            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index","Login"))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username: </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("Username")</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password: </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("Password")</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line to your view:

```
@model UserSample
```

You probable need to include the namespace there. `MyApp.Models.UserSample` for example.

Then you can use stronly typed html-helpers:

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)</td>
```

and

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password)</td>
```

You should decorate the `Index(UserSample user)` method with the `HttpPost` attribute:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Get method.
    UserSample model = new UserSample();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(UserSample user)
{
    //  POST method.
}
```

When you post the form now, the `UserSample` object should be populated with the values from the form.

If you don't understand model binding, I suggest you look into it. [This tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) might get you started.